# Java FX8 Tabs on the left side with horizontal tabs

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I require a tabbed pane with tabs on the left side, the tab text/graphic needs to be horizontal

I did this on Scenebuilder few months back.

However when I add additional tabs via Java code, the tabs is on the left side but the graphic text is vertical unlike the tabs created using Scene builder.

In the attached image first two tabs are created through Scenebuilder and they are in the correct orientation, the third one was dynamically added using Java code.

```
Tab studentAdmission = new Tab();
        studentAdmission.setContent((Parent)new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Customer_View.fxml")).load());


        studentAdmission.setGraphic(new Label("Student Admission"));
        mainTab.getTabs().add(studentAdmission);
```

[image]

Could some one advise why this tab doesn't rotate as the other one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just figured out after posting the question that you need to add a StackPane containing a group containing a label to achieve this.

```
  Tab studentAdmission = new Tab();
     studentAdmission.setContent((Parent)new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Customer_View.fxml")).load());

    Label l = new Label("Student Admission");
    l.setRotate(90);
    StackPane stp = new StackPane(new Group(l));
    studentAdmission.setGraphic(stp);
    mainTab.getTabs().add(studentAdmission);
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for the beautiful nastiness of that hack :-) Astonished that such hacking seems to be needed. And couldn't make it work: the width of the tab is always too small, as if the graphic weren't included into the pref calculation. Any further trick?

Comment: Do you refer to the tab size being small in my graphics or is it a problem that you face? You need to set size attributes on the stack pane for it to reflect on the Tab child, I know its silly though Ex:   StackPane stp = new StackPane(new Group(l));
   stp.setPrefHeight(160);

Comment: meant my problem in trying to reproduce your hack :-) Hmm .. still no luck. What's your jdk version?

Comment: JDK8 - I messed up my machine two nights before trying to build opencv, hence I have reinstalled everything and I currently don't have JDK 7 installed hence I am not able to test it for you right now.

Comment: don't worry - basically, I'm just curious :-) And thanks for the additional info!

Comment: You need to add tabpane.setRotateGraphic(true) before adding any tabs to it, this is not clear in my code as it is done on the FXML side.

Comment: After struggling a bit to reproduce this: you need to set on the TabPane the Tab Max Height to a higher value. So in Scene Builder you end up having TabPane (Rotate Graphic true, tab max/min height = 120) > Tab (no label) > Tab Graphic = StackPane (you may need to put the StackPane in the tab then try and move it again on the tab to make the "Graphic spot" appear) > Group > Label (with text, Rotate 90°)

Answer (score 2):

I needed to get something similar to this, but with left-aligned titles. I ended up with this solution.

[image: TabPane result]

`TabPane` setup:

```java
TabPane tabPane = new TabPane();
tabPane.setSide(Side.LEFT);
tabPane.setRotateGraphic(true);
tabPane.setTabMinHeight(200); // Determines tab width. I know, its odd.
tabPane.setTabMaxHeight(200);
tabPane.getStyleClass().add("horizontal-tab-pane");
```

`Tab` setup:

```java
Tab tab = new Tab(title, content);
tab.setClosable(false);
tab.setGraphic(graphic); // Graphic required. If you don't want one, use an empty label.
Platform.runLater(() -> {
    // Get the "tab-container" node. This is what we want to rotate/shift for easy left-alignment.
    // You can omit the last "getParent()" with a few tweaks for centered labels
    Parent tabContainer = tab.getGraphic().getParent().getParent();
    tabContainer.setRotate(90);
    // By default the display will originate from the center.
    // Applying a negative Y transformation will move it left.
    // Should be the 'TabMinHeight/2'
    tabContainer.setTranslateY(-100);
});
```

And the css:

```css
.horizontal-tab-pane *.tab {
    /* Determines the tab height */
    -fx-pref-width: 60px; 
    /* Everything else is just aesthetics */
    -fx-padding: 20px;
    -fx-background-insets: 2 -1 -1 -1;
    -fx-border-width: 1 0 1 1;
    -fx-border-color: rgb(55, 55, 56) black black black;
}
.horizontal-tab-pane *.tab:selected {
    -fx-background-color: rgb(45, 45, 46);
    -fx-border-color: rgb(75, 125, 200) black rgb(45, 45, 46) black;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    // Firstly
    tabPane.setSide(Side.LEFT);
    tabPane.setRotateGraphic(true);        

    Label l = new Label("Titel Tab1");
    l.setRotate(90);
    StackPane stp = new StackPane(new Group(l));
    stp.setRotate(90);
    tab1.setGraphic(stp);

    l = new Label("Titel Tab2");
    l.setRotate(90);
    stp = new StackPane(new Group(l));
    stp.setRotate(90);
    tab2.setGraphic(stp);

    tabPane.setTabMinHeight(100);
    tabPane.setTabMaxHeight(100);
```